# Node.js express how to exit from route

Tags: node.js, express

I my application, i have two buttons on client html page,

START=> this call a service which calls router.get('check/start')

PAUSE=> this call a service which calls router.get('check/pause')

In my server.js ,

```
const check = require('./routes/check')
....
app.use('/check', check);
..
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.json({
      "message": "Welcome to the home location"
   });
});
....
```

and routes/check.js is,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = require('express').Router();
var JsonObj;
var io = req.app.get('socketio');
router.get('/start', function(req, res, next) {
    ReadFile(io);     
});

function ReadFile(io) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       myInterval = setInterval(function(){
            JsonObj.marks = parseInt(Math.random()*100);
            io.emit('data', JsonObj);   
        }, 1000);    

    })
}

router.get('/pause', function(req, res) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
 });

module.exports = router;
```

This code actually works for START and PAUSE buttons, but i also want to have CANCEL button which takes me out from route and render the home route. I am not getting idea, how to come out from route. I tried putting return 0; but it throws error.

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: You need to add `res.end()` methods to your router callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the `/` route, so you can use `res.redirect`;

```
router.get('/stop', function(req, res) {
  //do the stopping work
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

This will render the `/` route. And return `{ "message": "Welcome to the home location" }`

Comment: Thanks @Aritra Chakraborty. Yes this solution worked.